# Calling SSIS package from VB.NET with events

Tags: vb.net, ssis

It's really a question and an answer. I was trying to figure out how to open an SSIS package from within VB.NET and then expose the events from the package so that I could check on progress. I could not find any answers online for this. Turns out, it's quite simple.

Comment: I would answer my own question but Stack Overflow does not allow me to for 8 hours!

Comment: So I will post answer tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Windows Form code:

Private Sub loadSSISPackage(ByVal packageFile As String)

```
    If file.Exists(packageFile) AndAlso packageFile.EndsWith(".dtsx") Then
        Dim pkg As New Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package
        Dim app As New Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application
        Dim pkgResults As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult


        pkg = app.LoadPackage(packageFile, Nothing)

        Dim pkgEvents As New PackageEvents


        pkgResults = pkg.Execute(Nothing, Nothing, pkgEvents, Nothing, Nothing)
        MsgBox(pkgResults.ToString())
    Else
        Environment.Exit(-1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is the class I created:

Public Class PackageEvents
    Implements Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.IDTSEvents

```
Public Sub OnBreakpointHit(breakpointSite As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.IDTSBreakpointSite, breakpointTarget As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.BreakpointTarget) Implements Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.IDTSEvents.OnBreakpointHit

End Sub

Public Sub OnCustomEvent(taskHost As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost, eventName As String, eventText As String, ByRef arguments() As Object, subComponent As String, ByRef fireAgain As Boolean) Implements Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.IDTSEvents.OnCustomEvent

End Sub

Public Function OnError(source As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsObject, errorCode As Integer, subComponent As String, description As String, helpFile As String, helpContext As Integer, idofInterfaceWithError As String) As Boolean Implements Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.IDTSEvents.OnError

End Function

Public Sub OnExecutionStatusChanged(exec As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Executable, newStatus As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecStatus, ByRef fireAgain As Boolean) Implements Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.IDTSEvents.OnExecutionStatusChanged

End Sub

Public Sub OnInformation(source As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsObject, informationCode As Integer, subComponent As String, description As String, helpFile As String, helpContext As Integer, idofInterfaceWithError As String, ByRef fireAgain As Boolean) Implements Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.IDTSEvents.OnInformation
    Debug.Print(CStr(informationCode))
    Debug.Print(CStr(subComponent))
    Debug.Print(CStr(description))
    Debug.Print(CStr(helpFile))
    Debug.Print(CStr(helpContext))


End Sub

Public Sub OnPostExecute(exec As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Executable, ByRef fireAgain As Boolean) Implements Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.IDTSEvents.OnPostExecute

End Sub

Public Sub OnPostValidate(exec As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Executable, ByRef fireAgain As Boolean) Implements Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.IDTSEvents.OnPostValidate

End Sub

Public Sub OnPreExecute(exec As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Executable, ByRef fireAgain As Boolean) Implements Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.IDTSEvents.OnPreExecute

End Sub

Public Sub OnPreValidate(exec As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Executable, ByRef fireAgain As Boolean) Implements Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.IDTSEvents.OnPreValidate

End Sub

Public Sub OnProgress(taskHost As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost, progressDescription As String, percentComplete As Integer, progressCountLow As Integer, progressCountHigh As Integer, subComponent As String, ByRef fireAgain As Boolean) Implements Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.IDTSEvents.OnProgress


    'Debug.Print(progressDescription)
    'Debug.Print(CStr(taskHost.ExecutionStatus))
    'Debug.Print(CStr(percentComplete))
    'Debug.Print(CStr(progressCountLow))
    'Debug.Print(CStr(progressCountHigh))

End Sub

Public Function OnQueryCancel() As Boolean Implements Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.IDTSEvents.OnQueryCancel

End Function

Public Sub OnTaskFailed(taskHost As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost) Implements Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.IDTSEvents.OnTaskFailed

End Sub

Public Sub OnVariableValueChanged(DtsContainer As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsContainer, variable As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variable, ByRef fireAgain As Boolean) Implements Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.IDTSEvents.OnVariableValueChanged

End Sub

Public Sub OnWarning(source As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsObject, warningCode As Integer, subComponent As String, description As String, helpFile As String, helpContext As Integer, idofInterfaceWithError As String) Implements Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.IDTSEvents.OnWarning

End Sub
```

End Class

Note that all the sub's will appear automatically once the implements line is coded. Now all the SSIS package events can be trapped!

There would obviously be some work to do regarding cross marshalling on separate threads to get the SSIS event info to the form, but that's another story...